# VS2012 Add Reference is Grayed Out

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Just installed VS2012 Premium (not express, but the full product). I'm totally new to it and to web programming.

I'm following the tutorial in ASP.NET and when I get [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer) it tells me to

> "right-click References and select Add Reference from the right-click menu"

However, the "Add Reference" menu item is grayed out.

How do I get out of this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check a couple of things

1. Do you have the project selected?
2. Are you in debug mode?

I would ensure you are not in debug.  And try not having the projected selected but the folder called references.

Comment: Hey David - you are a genius! It was in debug mode. I guess it was because I clicked on the "play" button to see the rendering. Thanks.

Comment: I feel stupid... I manually edited my _.csproj_ a few times because that option was greyed out